# Unable to upload new file (<4MB) to SharePoint (ms graph api)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm trying to upload an attachment i get from Outlook to a folder inside a SharePoint document library.
I am Following the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request-to-upload-a-new-file

```js
fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/drive/items/${parentId}:/${attachment.name}:/content`, { 
      method: 'PUT', 
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accesToken}`, 
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      }),
      body: attachment.contentBytes
    })
```

All I get is an error with code: `-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException`

I've tried setting the body of the fetch request as a simple string such as "hello world" with testing purposes and still get the same error.

Any ideas?

Thx in advance

---

[EDIT]
I suspect I'm not building the URL right.
I haven't found the documentation for the parameter:

- {item-id} I'm assuming this ID is the folder's `parentReference.siteId` attribute.

Is that right?

Comment: Did you get this work ? I always get error `Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.`

Comment: yeah. Look at my own response :)

Comment: With regard to the error mentioned by @KebinLiu, I got the same until I added the colons in the URL, as specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright, so after some testing with the Microsoft Graph Explorer, I've found that the easiest way to upload a file to a SharePoint folder living inside a document library (distinct to the root document library) is to deal with it as a drive using the endpoint:

```
/drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request-to-upload-a-new-file)

In order to get the document library's **drive-id**, you can append to the graph query the odata parameter $expand=drive like:

```
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists?$expand=drive`
```

Then, alongside other attributes of the targetted document library, you will find the "drive" object, which holds the **drive-id** associated to the document library you want to upload the file to. So, you would make the PUT request like:

```js
fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/${libraryDriveId}/items/root:/${folderDisplayName}/${nameOfFile}:/content`, {
      method: 'PUT', 
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accesToken}`, 
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      }),
      body: BINARY_STREAM_OF_DATA
    }).then( (response) => {
      if (!response.ok) return response.json().then((json) => {throw json});
      return response.json();
    }).then( (json) => {
      //do whatever
    }).catch( (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    })
```

libraryDriv

- `libraryDriveId` comes from the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists?$expand=drive` request
- `/root:/${folderDisplayName}` means that the folder you are targetting inside the document library lives under "root:" (the root of the document library) followed by the `displayName` of the folder you want to upload the file to
- `nameOfFile` is the name of the file you want to upload