# MS Graph API file replace SharePoint ReactJS 404 item not found or stream issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the MS Graph API and ReactJS to download a file from SharePoint and then replace the file. I have managed the download part after using the `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` value. Here is the code that gets me the XML document from SharePoint.

```
export async function getDriveFileList(accessToken,siteId,driveId,fileName) {
  const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
  //https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{item-path}
  const files = await client
    .api('/sites/' + siteId + '/drives/' + driveId + '/root:/' + fileName)
    .select('id,name,webUrl,content.downloadUrl')
    .orderby('name')
    .get();
  //console.log(files['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl']);
  return files;
}
```

When attempting to upload the same file back up I get a `404 itemNotFound`error return. Because [this user was able to get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824303/unable-to-upload-new-file-4mb-to-sharepoint-ms-graph-api) I think I have the MS Graph API correct, although I am not sure I'm translating correctly to ReactJS syntax. Even though the error message says item not found I think MS Graph might actually be upset with how I'm sending the XML file back. The [Microsoft documentation for updating an existing file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) state the contents of the file in a stream should be returned. Since I've loaded the XML file into the state I'm not entirely sure how to send it back. The closest match I found involved converting a PDF to a blob so I tried that.

```
export async function putDriveFile(accessToken,siteId,itemId,xmldoc) {
  const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
  // /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
  let url = '/sites/' + siteId + '/drive/items/' + itemId + '/content';
  var convertedFile = null;
  try{
    convertedFile = new Blob(
        [xmldoc],
        {type: 'text/xml'});
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  const file = await client
    .api(url)
    .put(convertedFile);
  console.log(file);
  return file;
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's the way I'm sending the file back but the Graph API has some bugs so I can't entirely be sure. I was convinced I was getting the correct ID of the drive item but I've seen where the site ID syntax can be different with the Graph API so maybe it is the item ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for putting an (existing) file into a document library in SharePoint is actually `PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content` I also found this code below worked for taking the XML document and converting into a blob that could be uploaded

```
  var xmlText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this.state.xmlDoc);
  var blob = new Blob([xmlText], { type: "text/xml"});
  var file = new File([blob], this.props.location.state.fileName, {type: "text/xml",});
  var graphReturn = await putDriveFile(accessToken, this.props.location.state.driveId, this.state.fileId,file);
```